Prompt "fatal: bad revision 'origin/myBranch‘" when trying to push to remote
I am having a branch with name curDev1. I try to push it to remote and get the following error message
> git push origin curDev1:test-branch
fatal: bad revision 'origin/curDev1'
fatal: bad revision 'origin/curDev1'
... # push success

The push successes but there are 2 error message indicating there are bad revision.
I assume there is some bad remote branch so I try to delete the remote branch
> git push origin :curDev1
error: unable to delete 'curDev1': remote ref does not exist

Turn out there is no curDev1 in remote origin. So I turned to do some clean work locally
> git branch curDev2 origin/test-branch
> git checkout curDev2
> git branch -D curDev1

curDev1 get deleted locally. I then try to push curDev2 instead, problem happens again
> git push origin curDev2:test-branch
fatal: bad revision 'origin/curDev2'
fatal: bad revision 'origin/curDev2'
...

curDev2 is a new created branch, so I don't know how origin/curDev2 get involved.
I also do git fetch --prune and even git gc, but the problem still happens.
Any suggestion on how to identify the root cause of it?

What specifically are you trying to do with git push origin curDev1:test-branch - are you trying to push your local curDev1 branch to a remote branch named test-branch?

Yes, this is my intention

Have you installed any hook that is invoked by git push and uses origin/$branch in it?

You catch it! Turns out someone adding a pre-push hook which invokes git diff --stat --cached origin/${CUR_BRANCH} and it gives the prompt. Thank you for the hint @ElpieKay
